# Get multiple SQL rows with similar column value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a cron job where it publishes (inserting new into the database) an article. I was able to pull it through but there is one query I can't get to work. I'd like to print certain rows from another table that can be inserted to the article being published. Supposed I have this `another table` like this:

```
+----------+-------------+
| filename | released    |
+----------+-------------+
| tigers   | 2020-05-27  |
| wolves   | 2020-05-27  |
| earth    | 2020-05-27  |
| bamboo   | 2020-05-27  |
| glaciers | 2020-05-02  |
+----------+-------------+
```

How can I print the result of the filenames as:

```
bamboo, earth, tigers, wolves
```

so that the cron can insert it to the `article table`'s specified column with the same format? I've tried using this query below but it only returns one result, which is the `tigers` filename.

```
SELECT filename,
    GROUP_CONCAT(filename ORDER BY filename ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM table
    WHERE released='2020-05-27'
    GROUP BY released
```

Many thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Remove `GROUP BY released` and `filename` from the select list.

Comment: @forpas Hi, I removed the GROUP BY and filename from SELECT and it returned nothing at all. Should I use `echo $row['filename'];` to print the comma-separated result to check it or not?

Comment: Personally, I could not able to understand the explanation. I think it would be better to reexplain the issue.

Comment: I can't help you with php but the query should be like this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d9zgZYB3ZFnZt3bGmX3soE/0

Comment: Works for me https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/edAtThWmCcW4uD6XGRAB5j/0: `bamboo, earth, tigers, wolves`.

Comment: @TheImpaler Hi, is it possible to echo/print the comma-separated result using the query you have? If so, how? Because using my own query, it only echoes 1 result, which is the `tigers` instead of the `bamboo, earth, tigers, wolves` result. Many thanks!

Comment: @Aki Yes, click on the link and then "Run" the query, You'll see a **single** VARCHAR value with the comma-separated list of filenames.

Comment: @TheImpaler I did, but I'm not sure how to echo them via PHP. I used your query as `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and I'm trying to use `echo $row['filename'];` to print the result but I don't see any when I run the PHP file. I guess I'm doing it wrong..?

Comment: @Aki I'm sorry, unfortunately I cannot help you with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Using [TheImpaler](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/edAtThWmCcW4uD6XGRAB5j/0)'s query, I managed to solve what I'm trying to get with the following code:

```
$get = $database->query("SELECT released, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(filename ORDER BY filename ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM another
    WHERE released='2020-05-27'
    GROUP BY released");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($get);
echo $row['1']; // Prints the comma-separated result of the filenames
echo print_r($row); // Prints the entire row
```

Many thanks for the comments, it gave me an idea and had my query validated!